# L'emploi de « de facto » et de « de jure » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, latin

De ce que j'ai compris, l'expression « de facto » signifierait « dans les faits », et l'expression « de jure » signifierait « dans la loi ».

Je me demandais alors si cette phrase était correcte :

> La fraude fiscale est punie *de jure* mais ne l'est pas *de facto* pour les politiciens

qui signifierait :

> La fraude fiscale est punie selon la loi mais ne l'est pas, dans les faits, pour les politiciens

Comment: de facto = en fait/réalité

Comment: J'emploierai plutôt « par la loi » dans cette phrase.

Comment: Comme c'est une expression latine [les pages wikipedia anglaises pour de jure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_jure) et [de facto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto) (très complètes) peuvent avantageusement être utilisées. En tant que français natif, je n'ai jamais entendu "de jure" ce qui explique que la page française n'existe pas...

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas Merci pour les liens wikipedia anglais, je n'avais pas pensé à regarder cela dans une autre langue que le français pour le coup !

Comment: Perhaps the author meant that fiscal fraud is generally supposed to be punished, but is not in fact punished for politicians? The sentence does indeed seem poorly worded. P.S. Where did you find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quelques notes et références. Chez [*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/de_jure/23008) on a pour *de jure* « (adverbe [...] selon le droit). Formule permettant d'opposer une situation, une reconnaissance juridique à une situation, à une reconnaissance de fait. (S'oppose à [*de facto*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/de_facto/22574).) », un peu comme on le dit [ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19456), formule qu'on présente ensuite comme une locution latine [*courante*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3799) à la BDL (la barre est haute), tout comme *de facto*, peut-être [plus usuel](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+jure%2Cde+facto%2Cex+post+facto%2Cipso+facto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%20jure%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cde%20facto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cex%20post%20facto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cipso%20facto%3B%2Cc0)...

Force est de constater qu'aussi peu de locutions emploient *facto* ([*ipso facto*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ipso_facto/44211), par une conséquence obligée ; [*ex post facto*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex_post_facto), à partir d'après le fait, *a posteriori*, retroactivement etc.) que l'ablatif *jure* de [*jus, juris*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=jus) (hormis *de jure uxoris*, on a que *in utroque jure*, et *neminem lædit qui suo jure utitur*, sans la préposition, qui l'emploient à première vue dans une liste [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_locutions_latines) de locutions latines). Les premières semblent plus génériques et ça explique peut-être pourquoi on les connaît davantage...

Par ailleurs on peut noter qu'en anglais, on mentionne sur [*AHDotEL*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=de%20jure&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) adverbe et adjectif (voir exemples sur [*ODO*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/de-jure?q=de%20jure)). On peut voir s'articuler certains défis de traduction comme avec le [*de jure standard*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8383238) ; l'idée de *norme formelle*, et l'adverbe *formellement*, pourront être utiles.

---

Personnellement j'ai l'impression que *de jure* est plus usuel en adjectif qualifiant un concept ou formant un nom composé, qu'en adverbe dans la phrase (comme dans l'exemple), et *de jure* n'est certainement déjà pas très usuel en français si on se fie aux commentaires etc. Ça relève davantage du domaine juridique<sup>1</sup>, c'est savant et très latinisant, surtout si on autorise la mainmise de la syntaxe latine sur la phrase avec l'adverbe plutôt que de formuler un énoncé beaucoup plus clair, à mon avis, comme celui qui suit dans la question (et certaines [prépositions](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19443/lemploi-de-de-facto-et-de-de-jure#comment37139_19443) sont peut-être plus précises en effet). Autrement c'est un style de langue qui s'appuie sur des locutions latines, et on a ce choix, qu'il faudra assumer, surtout si on prononce [deː juːrɛ] et que l'interlocuteur ne reconnait pas du tout le mot... Voir aussi [*avoir deux poids deux mesures*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/poids/61976/locution?q=deux%20poids#164868) ou simplement la définition de [laxisme](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/laxisme/46491?q=laxisme#46413) (dans l'application des règles), par exemple, pour des manières de traiter du sujet différemment.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Par exemple, un illustre juriste français comme [Pothier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert-Joseph_Pothier) traite de présomptions [*juris et de jure*](https://books.google.com/books?id=uIYPAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22de%20jure%22%20pothier&pg=RA1-PA303#v=onepage&q=%22de%20jure%22&f=false) dans un sens bien particulier (*irréfragables*, faut-il lire). Par ailleurs, l'emploi en ablatif se trouve dans le titre du premier chapitre du premier livre (*De Justicia et Jure*) des [*Institutes*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k57110572/f20.item) de Justinien, un segment d'une [œuvre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_iuris_civilis) fondatrice en droit. Tout ceci n'est pas directement relié à l'emploi en français, mais dans tout domaine où on s'appuie sur cette histoire ou sur cette tradition on reconnaît sans doute la dichotomie *de jure/de facto*, en plus du lexique latin, omniprésent, dont la préposition latine [*de*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=de) pour l'*origine/au sujet de*.</sub>

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour cette explication et surtout pour ces sources très précises ! Je laisserai alors l'usage de "de jure" au domaine juridique.

Comment: @Joel Derfner Je ne sais pas pourquoi vous avez retiré votre réponse, c'était tout à fait bien à mon avis, et d'un bon français. Le concept du site est vraiment celui des réponses multiples et non pas d'une seule et et unique bonne réponse. Merci !

Comment: @Plimee Je vous en prie ! Comme l'illustrait la réponse de Joel D., je pense que pour un Américain les termes sont peut-être associés à l'histoire de la ségrégation raciale ; on le voit aussi désigner une société (de jure corporation) ayant complété les formalités requises par la loi, par opposition à une qui ne l'a pas fait etc (voir par exemple [ceci](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/de+jure)). Enfin j'ai vu _de jure claims_ dans _Crusader Kings_ (jeu d'ordi.) C'est uniquement une impression mais j'ai l'impression que c'est plus usuel ou au moins plus connu, en anglais. Merci !